# Angular Material - Directive mat-card doesn't do anything

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material in this project and everything else seems to work just fine so far. But for some reason adding `mat-card` isn't doing anything. From what I've seen elsewhere it should at least be adding the class `.mat-card`, but it's not even doing that.

The code is `<h2 mat-card >Details</h2>`. I also tried it on a `<div>` element: still nothing.

The module `MatCardModule` is imported in exactly the same fashion as every other module I'm using in this project.

Tried adding margins as suggested on another question here. Didn't fix it. Anything I could try?

Comment: `mat-card` should be used as a component like `<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mat-card** is an element, not an attribute. You can either use it as an element or add a class="mat-card" for h2 tag.

Check the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnaboe?file=app/card-fancy-example.html

Answer (score 1):

`mat-card` should be used as a [component](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/card/card.ts#L151) like

```
<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>
```

Within `mat-card` you can add `mat-card-content`, `mat-card-title` etc

Example from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples)

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
      A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
      bred for hunting.
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Thank you. What a dumb question, heh. Hopefully this will be useful to other people.